# Bash - Log all output to a file but also include a timestamp in the log

Tags: bash

Using this simple example, I want to be able to log everything into a file with a timestamp prepended before each command. I do not want the timestamp to show on the console.

My example below prints the timestamp on the screen but does not print it to the log.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec > >(tee -i logfile.txt | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]')

exec 2>&1

echo "Sending files to S3 ..."
s3cmd MYFILE s3://MYBUCKET/
echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `ts` before `tee`, and as you don't want to alter stdout, a nested process substitution:

```
exec > >(tee -a >(ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' > logfile.txt))
```

Comment: Also, you may be able to use `ts '[%F %T]'`, check your `strftime(3)` man page

Comment: THANKS ALOT! I was beating my head for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the moreutils tools, you can use the `pee` command:

```
exec > >(pee cat "ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' > logfile.txt")
```